# 2 Pulleys moving towards each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

[image: find velocity of A]

2 stands B, with pulleys mounted on them move towards each other with velocity V
A rope is passing over the pulleys and a block A is attached to the rope 
Find the velocity of A when rope is at angle theta 
Please refer figure for any doubt in the language of question.

MY ATTEMPT
[image: this is my attempt]

I was able to find 2 equations but there are 3 variables, please help me in finding the 3rd equation.

Comment: Try energy conservation to find another equation.

Comment: @TausifHossain Thanks for the hint, but I haven't been taught energy conservation yet.

Comment: please can anybody help

Answer (score 2):

You should simplify your equations - get rid of $\theta$. Next, use the symmetry of the situation to look at just one pulley moving towards the middle of the room. The other quantity we need is the slack in the rope - the difference between the width of the room and the length of the rope. Let's call that difference $2S$ (S for "slack").

The hypotenuse (rope hanging from pulley to weight) will have length $S+x$, and this results in a height $y$. So now we know

$$(S+x)^2 + x^2 = y^2\\
S^2 + 2Sx + 2x^2 = y^2\\
(2S+4x)dx = 2y dy\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{S+2x}{y}$$

If we have the rope at a certain height $y$ for a given $x$, we can compute $S$. And now you have what you need so solve this (you don't need to solve for x and y; you just need the relationship - that is, the derivative of y with respect to x).

Comment: shouldn't the hypotenuse be S-x

Comment: I am not able to understand your solution can you please illustrate it in a figure.